# SDL error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

am trying to test SDL using this codes :

```
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Surface * screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640,480,32,SDL_SWSURFACE);
    bool IsRuning = true;
    Uint32 Start;
    SDL_Event Event;

    while (IsRuning)
    {
        Start = SDL_GetTicks();
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&Event))
        {
            switch (Event.type)
            {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                IsRuning = false;
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        if(1000/30 > (SDL_GetTicks() - Start))
            SDL_Delay(1000/30 > (SDL_GetTicks() - Start));
    }

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

and am linking this libs :

```
SDLmain.lib
SDL.lib
OpenGL32.lib
glu32.lib
```

when am trying to debug it it gives me those errors :-

```
Warning 1   warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'msvcrt.lib' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library    c:\Users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestSDL\TestSDL\MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)

Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___report_rangecheckfailure referenced in function _redirect_output   c:\Users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestSDL\TestSDL\SDLmain.lib(SDL_win32_main.obj)

Error   3   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestSDL\Debug\TestSDL.exe  1
```

what ma missing here?!!

Answer (score 1):

Probably one of `SDLmain.lib` or `SDL.lib` links against `msvcrt.lib`, which is the MicroSoft Visual C RunTime library. However you're compiling a debug build, and debug builds depend on the debug variant of the runtime library. Those two runtime libraries, they are conflicting.

The solution would be to use specific debug builds of the SDL libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You need to change the line:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

to

```
int main(int argc, char* argv)
```